# How to execute on-premises python script from ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a python script resides in an Azure VM. This script uses a few local files from this VM. I need to create an ADF  pipeline which will execute this python script residing in this on-premises VM. As the script is placed on-premises, I can't use any cluster activity of ADF. So Basically the pipeline should connect to the VM and trigger the script execution. I could think of an option of using Custom Activity of ADF and trigger Powershell command from there to this on-premises python script. But not sure how to connect to on-premises scripts.

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 0):

After my researching, you do could run Python script in ADF custom activity. However, based on the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity#custom-activity),you need to rely on Azure Batch Service to put your scripts and dependencies to the folder path in the Azure Batch Service. So, I think it's properly for you to execute on-premises Python scripts situation.

I provide you with a workaround.

step1: expose an endpoint to executing your on-premises Python scripts, of course, the local files could be touched.

step2: then use [VPN gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-vpngateways) to get access to network channels between on-premises and Azure side.

step3: use [Web activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity) in ADF to invoke the exposed endpoint and get executing results.